# Cmd + Shift + 4 no longer works

Tags: macos-highsierra

`Cmd` + `Shift` + `4` used to allow me to take a screenshot of a selected area (which would save). Now it instead takes a screenshot of a window, the entire window.

I have tried remapping the keyboard shortcut in Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screen Shots but even when I remap it, it performs the wrong action (grabbing the window instead of the selection).

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Cmd/Shift/4 toggles 'dragged screen area' & 'this selected window' using the Spacebar. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Tetsujin - thank you! That solved it